# Play framework: Why the cookie isn't showing

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, session-cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to set a simple cookie with a domain but it seems that it doesn't get added to the browser's cookie store.

Here's how I added the cookie

```
response().setCookie("clientauthtoken", "asdasd", 5000, "/test", "test.com", false, false);
```

And if I check in the cookie manager (a plugin for Firefox to manage cookies) it doesn't show the cookie I added.

If I check in the session, yes it's there

```
    for (play.mvc.Http.Cookie cockie: response().cookies()) {
        Logger.info(" name " + cockie.name());
        Logger.info(" value " + cockie.value());
        Logger.info(" domain " + cockie.domain());
    }
```

This happens only if I added the domain (test.com). If I set the domain null or an empty string and try to add the cookie again, then it is showing both the browser's cookie store and in the session. So what I'm missing here? Or is it not possible to add a cookie with a domain.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't domain be added as Option? [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Cookie)

Comment: Yes, but you are talking about the Cookie object. I'm setting the cookie via response().setCookie in that the domain is just a String. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3-M1/JavaResponse

Comment: I've tried the Scala version and it's showing fine, I tested it in Chrome. Is it working with other domains? Have you tried typing the exact example as in documentation?

Comment: No, it is not working for any domain and yes I have tried exact sample in the document as well, but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're adding a cookie with a domain, you can't test it when browsing to `localhost`. What you need to do in order to test it is to edit the `hosts` settings of your OS (for linux and OS X it's `/etc/hosts`) and add:

```
127.0.0.1 test.com
```

Then you can test things via `http://test.com:9000`