# Cookie not setting in Scala Play

Tags: reactjs, scala, cookies, playframework, axios

I am trying to set a cookie from a response when using the scala play framework. I am creating a cookie called session with its value being a UUID (I do know play comes with its own session management).
I can see the response headers contain the set cookie instruction, but the cookie ins't being set.

Below is the scala code in the action in the controller where the cookie is set

```
val cookie= Cookie("session",
    sessionToken,
    httpOnly=true,
    sameSite=Some(Cookie.SameSite.Lax))

Ok(Json.toJson(res))
  .withCookies(cookie)
// Also tried with .bakeCookies() after the withCookies() call
```

I can see the cookie header in the response in both FireFox and Chrome. They both show what appears to be a correctly formed cookie in their respective response cookie viewer in their developer tools.

```
Set-Cookie: session=c0174ed1-ebd3-4a8d-a5b2-5b09a3fe616b; SameSite=Lax; Path=/; HTTPOnly
```

However, in both browsers the cookie does not get set. I have tried true and false httpOnly, and messing with the maxAge value. I have tried setting the domain to a url and then setting the url in the hosts file [as suggested here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23742479/12868925)

The URL on the react frontend is

```
http://localhost:49161/login/hydrate
```

and the endpoint in play is

```
http://localhost:49162/user/login/rehydrate
```

I did also try setting the path to /login/hydrate/ on the cookie

The react code on the front end

```
     // Inside async function
     // methodStrings[method] = "post" in this request
     axios[methodStrings[method]](url, params)
        .then(result => {
          resolve(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(`Error with request to ${url} - ${err}`);
          reject(err.response.status);
        });
```

And then I console.log the result from awaiting the request

Comment: An HTTP only cookie is not visible from JS

Comment: @cchantep yeah I figured that, but it’s still not showing up in the browsers cookie viewers when http only cookies from other websites are. Also, As I said I tried to generate my cookie both as http only and not - and neither of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in axios (and/or browser).

Based on this issue [Cookies headers are present but Cookies are not stored in browser #1553](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1553#) you need to set withCredentials Axios config to store cookies in browser after request:

```js
  axios.post('domain.com', {
    name: 'name',
    password: 'password'
  }, {
    //AxiosRequestConfig parameter
    withCredentials: true //correct
  })
```

Comment: I have made that change and now it works perfectly, thanks for your help